# Как в sql добавить к datetime 7 дней

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно выбрать все столбики в **end_time** и добавить к ним 7 дней.
Мой примерный код:

```
select * from purchases where end_time > Cast('2022-*-*' as datetime)+7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **MySQL** Добавить дни можно при помощи функции **DATE_ADD()**

```
select end_time, DATE_ADD(end_time, INTERVAL 7 DAY) from purchases;
```

UPD по комментарию *Что дальше делать? Оно не изменяет*

Если вам надо изменить значение поля **end_time** прибавив к нему 7 дней, то запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
update purchases set end_time = DATE_ADD(end_time, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Если обновлять надо не все записи, то не забудте добавить условие **WHERE**

Comment: https://ibb.co/x1HC0yp
Что дальше делать? Оно не изменяет

Comment: @Rysik5318 **Оно** не изменяет, потому что *оно* это **SELECT** (СЕЛЕКТ). Для изменения надо использовать **UPDATE**. Обновил ответ, добавил update.